# hacer un clasificador de spam en python

Tags: python

Buenas tengo que hacer un código que especifique si es spam o no. Tengo que hacer un entrenador y después uno que mire si es o no. Pero nunca he manejado python y estoy muy perdido.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo duda es como puedo hacer el sumatorio que hay en la formulas.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #sumatoria de la formula x^2 desde inferior hasta superior
def sumatoria(inferior,superior):#las entradas son los limites 
    resultado=0
    while superior!=(inferior-1):#este seria el limite inferior -1. 
        resultado+=superior**2#aqui va la formula
        superior-=1
    return resultado
```

mas o menos asi se puede hacer una sumatoria en python